# NEMA 5-15-P and C13 Compatibility?

Tags: power-supply, application-note

I have a Power Distribution Unit with C13 outputs. I am hoping to connect a NEMA 5-15-P device to it. Is this possible? It seems like it should be fine, but I fear I am overlooking something (similar to metric to imperial). My device takes 100 to 240 VAC or 100 to 120 VAC

Comment: The C13 connector is only rated for 10A maximum while NEMA 5-15-P goes up to 15A so it depends how much current your device requires and how much your PDU can supply. Apart from it not physically fitting, obviously.

Comment: @Finbarr oh im a dummy, I didn't notice NEMA 5-15 was a round prong compared to C13's straight prong.

Comment: @Finbarr If most my applications only take up to 10A, is there any recommended way to convert from 5-15-P to C13?

Comment: @bchang32 A proper power cord...? The entire point of IEC 60320 is that you can get power cords with a standard IEC 60320 socket on one end and a local standard power plug (like NEMA 5-15P) on the other.

Comment: If you mean plug something that is supposed to plug into a NEMA 5-15 into a C13 then there is no official way since the connector and attached wires are designed to compliment each other's current ratings.  I am sure that you could find some adapter cords on the internet with a 5-15 socket on one end and a C13 plug on the other but I do not recommend them since they're relying on you to not overload the C13 side because there's nothing stopping you from plugging a 15A load in.

Comment: @vir so from the device spec that I plan on connecting into it, it only draws 7.5A, so I should be fine?

Comment: @Hearth ok thanks, so as long as I make sure the current doesn't go above the rating, then I should be fine? In my case, I need to make sure it doesn't go above 10A due to the C13 being the lower of the ratings?

Comment: To be clear, I am telling you NOT to plug the 5-15 load into the C13.  While it may work for your specific situation now, any adapter that would convert from C13 to 5-15 will not be approved by anybody and creates a dangerous situation.  The safe, correct way to do it would be to get a PDU with a C19 connector or to get a 5-15 socket controlled by a C13 socket.

Comment: @vir why a C19 receptacle (sorry for the questions, just trying to learn)? Is it because the C19 can handle 16A (which is greater than the 15A)? The PDU is scoped has a C19. So would I just need a C20 to NEMA 5-15-P cable? (is that even a thing)
Also, for the latter, do you mean a C13 Receptacle that has the form factor of a 5-15 receptacle? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the C19/C20 can handle enough current to run anything that can be plugged into a 5-15.  The cord you're looking for is a C20 (C20 is the plug, C19 is the receptacle) to 5-15 adapter.  The other way would be to find an outlet strip that has a 5-15 socket on it and has an external control input.

Comment: @vir external control input? as in current limited to protect the user? I have scoped out an Eaton PDU that is managed (external control). So would the external control input just be used to current limit it? The 5-15 socket controlled by a C13 socket is confusing me. apologies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127515/discussion-between-vir-and-bchang32).